How do I deal with a type mismatch error in VBA?
My VB code keeps below and keeps generating a runtime error 13. Not sure why. Can someone point out what is wrong with the code below?
Sub GenerateUniqueData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim firstNames() As String
    Dim lastNames() As String
    Dim usedNames As Object
    Dim fullName As String
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set usedNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Clear existing data
    ws.Range("A2:E1001").Clear
    
    ' Add headers
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Full Name"
    ws.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Age"
    ws.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Height (cm)"
    ws.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Weight (kg)"
    ws.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Bone Density"
    
    ' Define larger arrays of first names and last names
    firstNames = Array("John", "Maria", "Robert", "Emily", "Michael", "Sarah", "David", "Lisa", "James", "Karen", _
                       "William", "Jennifer", "Richard", "Elizabeth", "Thomas", "Nancy", "Charles", "Patricia", "Daniel", "Linda", _
                       "Matthew", "Barbara", "Anthony", "Margaret", "Donald", "Susan", "Mark", "Dorothy", "Paul", "Jessica", _
                       "Steven", "Ashley", "Andrew", "Kimberly", "Kenneth", "Donna", "Joshua", "Carol", "George", "Michelle", _
                       "Kevin", "Amanda", "Brian", "Betty", "Edward", "Melissa", "Ronald", "Deborah", "Timothy", "Stephanie")
    
    lastNames = Array("Smith", "Garcia", "Johnson", "Chen", "Brown", "Davis", "Wilson", "Anderson", "Taylor", "Lee", _
                      "White", "Harris", "Martin", "Thompson", "Moore", "Young", "Allen", "King", "Wright", "Scott", _
                      "Green", "Baker", "Adams", "Nelson", "Hill", "Ramirez", "Campbell", "Mitchell", "Roberts", "Carter", _
                      "Phillips", "Evans", "Turner", "Torres", "Parker", "Collins", "Edwards", "Stewart", "Flores", "Morris", _
                      "Nguyen", "Murphy", "Rivera", "Cook", "Rogers", "Morgan", "Peterson", "Cooper", "Reed", "Bailey")
    
    ' Generate 1000 rows of data
    For i = 2 To 1001
        ' Generate unique full name
        Do
            fullName = firstNames(Int(Rnd() * UBound(firstNames))) & " " & lastNames(Int(Rnd() * UBound(lastNames)))
        Loop While usedNames.Exists(fullName)
        usedNames.Add fullName, Nothing
        
        ' Full Name
        ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = fullName
        
        ' Age
        ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(18, 80)
        
        ' Height
        ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(150, 200)
        
        ' Weight
        ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(Rnd(), 70, 15), 0)
        
        ' Bone Density
        ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = Round(Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(Rnd(), 1.2, 0.05), 2)
    Next i
    
    ' Format headers
    ws.Range("A1:E1").Font.Bold = True
    
    MsgBox "Data generation complete!", vbInformation
End Sub


It would be helpful to give the line of the error :-)
Dim firstNames() As String should be
Dim firstNames As Variant (and the other variable)
But i think you will have more problems in your code.
E.g. I'm not sure if Int(Rnd()) will always return 0

What line returns the error?

Generate Unique Data
The Two Options (Type Mismatch Error)
Sub TwoOptions()

    ' The 'Array' function produces a 1D Variant array.
    ' If you prepend 'VBA.', you're ensuring it is a zero-based array.
    Dim FirstNames() As Variant: FirstNames = VBA.Array( _
        "John", "Maria", "Robert", "Emily", "Michael")
    Debug.Print Join(FirstNames, ", ")
    
    ' The 'Split' function produces a 1D zero-based String array.
    Const FirstNamesList As String = "John,Maria,Robert,Emily,Michael"
    Dim sFirstNames() As String: sFirstNames = Split(FirstNamesList, ",")
    Debug.Print Join(FirstNames, ", ")

End Sub


Either way, consider putting these long arrays in two columns of a ((very) hidden) worksheet. The purpose of the worksheets is to hold data.
Theoretically, your Do Loop could take forever. Think about it: a full name existing in the dictionary is generated on each iteration. Although it works, it is not a good idea.

Main
Sub GenerateUniqueData()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Generate Unique Data"
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A1"
    Const SAMPLE_SIZE As Long = 10000
    
    Dim HEADERS() As Variant: HEADERS = VBA.Array( _
        "Full Name", "Age", "Height (cm)", "Weight (kg)", "Bone Density")

    Dim FIRST_NAMES() As Variant: FIRST_NAMES = VBA.Array( _
        "John", "Maria", "Robert", "Emily", "Michael", _
        "Sarah", "David", "Lisa", "James", "Karen", _
        "William", "Jennifer", "Richard", "Elizabeth", "Thomas", _
        "Nancy", "Charles", "Patricia", "Daniel", "Linda", _
        "Matthew", "Barbara", "Anthony", "Margaret", "Donald", _
        "Susan", "Mark", "Dorothy", "Paul", "Jessica", _
        "Steven", "Ashley", "Andrew", "Kimberly", "Kenneth", _
        "Donna", "Joshua", "Carol", "George", "Michelle", _
        "Kevin", "Amanda", "Brian", "Betty", "Edward", _
        "Melissa", "Ronald", "Deborah", "Timothy", "Stephanie")
    
    Dim LAST_NAMES() As Variant: LAST_NAMES = VBA.Array( _
        "Smith", "Garcia", "Johnson", "Chen", "Brown", _
        "Davis", "Wilson", "Anderson", "Taylor", "Lee", _
        "White", "Harris", "Martin", "Thompson", "Moore", _
        "Young", "Allen", "King", "Wright", "Scott", _
        "Green", "Baker", "Adams", "Nelson", "Hill", _
        "Ramirez", "Campbell", "Mitchell", "Roberts", "Carter", _
        "Phillips", "Evans", "Turner", "Torres", "Parker", _
        "Collins", "Edwards", "Stewart", "Flores", "Morris", _
        "Nguyen", "Murphy", "Rivera", "Cook", "Rogers", _
        "Morgan", "Peterson", "Cooper", "Reed", "Bailey")
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    
    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no active sheet!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then
        MsgBox "The active sheet is not a worksheet!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    ' Return all full names in a 1D one-based String array ('FullNames').
    
    Dim FullNamesCount As Long:
    FullNamesCount = (UBound(FIRST_NAMES) + 1) * (UBound(LAST_NAMES) + 1)
    
    Dim FullNames() As String: ReDim FullNames(1 To FullNamesCount)
    
    Dim f As Long, l As Long, r As Long
    
    For f = 0 To UBound(FIRST_NAMES)
        For l = 0 To UBound(LAST_NAMES)
            r = r + 1
            FullNames(r) = FIRST_NAMES(f) & " " & LAST_NAMES(l)
        Next l
    Next f
    
    ' Validate the number of records.
    ' If e.g. you use 'SAMPLE_SIZE = 10000' and there are only 50 * 50 = 2500
    ' combinations, you can get only 2500 distinct full names.
    
    Dim SampleSize As Long: SampleSize = SAMPLE_SIZE
    
    Select Case SampleSize
        Case Is > FullNamesCount: SampleSize = FullNamesCount
        ' I don't think this matters but this is the place to put it.
        'Case Is < FullNamesCount: ReDim Preserve FullNames(1 To SampleSize)
    End Select
    
    ' Shuffle the array.
    
    ShuffleArray FullNames, SampleSize
    
    ' Write the results to a 2D one-based array ('Data').
    
    ' Define array.
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = SampleSize + 1 ' headers
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(HEADERS) + 1
    Dim Data() As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    ' Write headers to array.
    For r = 1 To cCount
        Data(1, r) = HEADERS(r - 1) ' Data is one-based, HEADERS is zero-based
    Next r
    
    ' Write data to array.
    With Application
        For r = 2 To rCount
            Data(r, 1) = FullNames(r - 1) ' 'FullNames' has no headers
            Data(r, 2) = .RandBetween(18, 80) ' age
            Data(r, 3) = .RandBetween(150, 200) ' height
            Data(r, 4) = .RoundUp(.Norm_Inv(Rnd(), 70, 15), 0) ' weight
            Data(r, 5) = .Round(.Norm_Inv(Rnd(), 1.2, 0.05), 2) ' bone density
        Next r
    End With
    
    ' Write the values from the array to the sheet.
    
    With ws.Range(FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS).Resize(, cCount)
        ' Clear columns.
        .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).Clear
        ' Write new.
        .Resize(rCount).Value = Data
        ' Format.
        .Font.Bold = True
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
        
    MsgBox "Data generation complete.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub

Help
Sub ShuffleArray(ByRef Arr As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal SampleSize As Variant)
    
    Dim First As Long: First = LBound(Arr)
    Dim UB As Long: UB = UBound(Arr)
    Dim Last As Long: Last = UB - 1
    
    Dim sLast As Long:
    If Not IsMissing(SampleSize) Then
        If IsNumeric(SampleSize) Then
            sLast = SampleSize + First - 1
            If sLast < Last Then Last = sLast
        End If
    End If
    
    Dim Temp As Variant, i As Long, j As Long
    
    For i = First To Last
        ' Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
        j = Int((UB - i + 1) * Rnd + i)
        Temp = Arr(i): Arr(i) = Arr(j): Arr(j) = Temp
    Next i

End Sub


Thanks so much for your help. This now works perfectly for me!!
